# Having trouble while listing of Array from shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, docker, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to return the below output as a list of Array from shell script.

```
{
"volume":[
{
"name":"logs",
"path":"/var/log"
},
{
"name":"logs2",
"path":"/var/log1"
}
]
}
```

From shell script, I am trying as below after defining as shown

#!/bin/bash
volume=$1

```
   arrVol=(${volume//,/ })
    portsLen=${#arrVol[@]}
    volume=""
    for((i=0;i<$portsLen;i++)); do volume+=" -v "${arrVol[i]}; done
```

docker run -d --name $dockerContainerName $volume $dockerPorts $dockerImagePath

When run through Jenkins this script is not being pulled correctly the way we would require.
Need the format: -v logs2:/var/log

Tried the below using jq as well with no luck

```
#for item in "${volume[@]}"; do vol+=" -v "$(jq '.logName' <<< "$item")":"$(jq '.logPath' <<< "$item"); echo "$vol"; done

#for((i=0;i<${#volume[*]};i++)); do vol+=" -v "${volume[i]'.logName'}":"${volume[i]'.logPath'};echo "$vol"; done
```

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. What are the inputs? You do show the desired output. JSON is quite tricky to generate with bash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `jq` with `declare`:

```sh
$ cat input.json
{
  "volume": [
    {
      "name": "logs",
      "path": "/var/log"
    },
    {
      "name": "logs2",
      "path": "/var/log1"
    }
  ]
}

$ declare -A a="($(jq -r '.volume[] | @sh "[\(.name)]=\(.path)"' input.json))"

$ echo "${a[logs]}"
/var/log

$ echo "${a[logs2]}"
/var/log1
```

---

Edit: As it is not clear whether the above is what you want, or rather the other way around, here's the latter:

```sh
$ echo "${a[logs]}"
/var/log

$ echo "${a[logs2]}"
/var/log1

$ jq -n '{volume:
    $ARGS.positional
    | [.[:length/2], .[length/2:]]
    | transpose
    | map({name:.[0], path:.[1]})
  }' --args "${!a[@]}" "${a[@]}"
{
  "volume": [
    {
      "name": "logs2",
      "path": "/var/log1"
    },
    {
      "name": "logs",
      "path": "/var/log"
    }
  ]
}
```